# How do you configure a MultipartResolver for limiting by the number of files instead of size?

Tags: java, xml, spring-mvc

Currently I have the code that limits the file upload by maxUoloadSize of a Multipartfile. I want to upload 200-300 files at once and each of them are around 1MB. Is there a way that I can configure the bean to limit by the number of files being uploaded (around 200)? But, the upload size of a single should be still 10MB. I am using Spring 3.0.5 MVC framework.

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <!-- 10 megs is 10485760 bytes.-->
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="10486784"/>
</bean>
```

Any suggestion is appreciated....thanks!!!

Answer (score 0):

No you can't with CommonsMutipartResolver...
But you can if you create your own mutlipart resolver by extending CommonsMutipartResolver!